# Backbone.js and Handlebars - Using grunt-contrib-handlebars

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, gruntjs

I'm just wondering if anyone has had experience using this plugin in a backbone project.

Instead of having all my script template tags in a single index file, I wanted to house my templates in the same directory as my views that required them.

So I was hoping i could use the node option to require the local template and render to it and then append to an #id on my index file (which I'll sort out laster).

So basically I have my handlebars template (template.hbs) and its compiled js (template.js) alongside my backbone view, index.coffee.

```
public
   |_ coffee
      |_views
        |_card
           |_list
              index.coffee
              template.hbs
              template.js
```

Just as a reference, my grunt file looks like this:

```
handlebars: {
      compile: {
        options: {
          namespace: 'MyApp.Templates',
          node: true
        },
        files: {
          "public/coffee/views/card/list/template.js": "public/coffee/views/card/list/template.hbs"
        }
      }
    },
```

In my backbone view (index.coffee) I was hoping to require the handlebars template like so:

```
class CardList extends Backbone.View
    template: require('./template')


    … 
    do some other shiz
    …


render: =>
    template = Handlebars.compile($(this.template).html())
    html = template
        model: this.model
    $(this.el).html(html)
```

Rendering this is spitting out this error in the inspector:

```
Uncaught [object Object]

> template = handlebars.compile($(this.template).html());
```

I obviously dont know what I'm doing, so I'm hoping someone could shed some light on how I can use this plugin properly.

I'm using grunt-contrib-handlebars v0.3.5

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [Take a look this solution. I implemented it with handlebars and browserify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511292/grunt-contrib-handlebars-configuration-issue/26753155#26753155)

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to achieve that by [building the files object dynamically](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically).

Maybe something like this, although I'm not sure if `cwd` supports globbing patterns. I'm also not sure if `dest` is relative to `cwd`. If this is not the case, this will not work, but it's worth a shot.

```
handlebars: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      namespace: 'MyApp.Templates',
      node: true
    },
    // Glob for a directory of files, builds the files object, then map each
    // one to a new destination file.
    expand: true,
    cwd: './public/coffee/views/*',
    src: '**/*.hbs',
    dest: './',
    ext: '.js'
  }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Look inside your template.js file that you're including.  grunt-comtrib-handlbars should have precompiled it into a Javascript function for you, so there's no need to call Handlebars.compile anymore.  You could just remove that template = Handlebars.compile line.