# grunt-contrib-handlebars configuration issue

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, handlebars.js

I have an issue with the configuration of "grunt-contrib-handlebars", below is my setup at the moment.

```
handlebars: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            namespace: "my.namespace"
        },
        files: {
            "<%= dist %>/templates/templates.js": "<%= src %>/templates/*.handlebars"
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I get at the moment:

my.namespace["src/templates/baseTemplate.handlebars"]

This is what I want:

my.namespace["baseTemplate"]

So I can call the templates like this:

```
my.namespace.baseTemplate(templateObj);
```

Is it possible to get this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look my solution

[image]

I implemented it with browserify.

1. I generated a .js file that contains all my templates.
2. Than I required it with browserify. Example:

```js
var templates = require('templates/all_templates_in_this_js_file_without_extension')();
```

3.And now I can use it like backbonejs template

```js
Backbone.View.extend({
 template: templates.product, //or templates['product']
 render: function(){
   this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()))
 }
});
```